# Browser is launch, then a Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have Ruby24 x64 installed with webdrivers and chromedriver. 
In the irb I type

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new
```

A Chrome browser is launched. In the irb after about :30 seconds I get an error message: Net::ReadTimeout

I've looked on Stackoverflow and the corners of the Internet. I can not figure out what is causing this.

The whole message:

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:154:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:164:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1446:in `block in transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1416:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `block in request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:877:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/http/default.rb:123:in `response_for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/http/default.rb:78:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/bridge.rb:170:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/bridge.rb:103:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
remote/bridge.rb:54:in `handshake'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
chrome/driver.rb:58:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
common/driver.rb:46:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
common/driver.rb:46:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.
rb:86:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/browser.rb:48:in `initiali
ze'
        from (irb):2:in `new'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what code are you using to initialize your browser?

Comment: require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new

Comment: I discovered I need to do this
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'